# Why does Python give recursion error for using a method that belongs to an external package

Tags: python, recursion, statistics

I'm trying to build functions that calculate the mean, median and mode of a given list.  For mode only, I'm using `from statistics import mode` (everything else is manual) but when it comes to outputting the result, only the line of code using the `mode()` method gives me a recursion error.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from statistics import mode

dataFrame = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/forest-fires/forestfires.csv")

area = dataFrame['area'].tolist()
rain = dataFrame['rain'].tolist()

months = dataFrame['month'] = dataFrame['month'].map({'jan': 1, 'feb': 2, 'mar': 3, 'apr': 4, 'may': 5, 'jun': 6, 'jul': 7, 'aug': 8, 'sep': 9, 'oct': 10, 'nov': 11, 'dec': 12}).tolist()

def mean(numbers):
  meanOfNumbers = (sum(numbers))/(len(numbers))
  return meanOfNumbers

def median(numbers):
  if(len(numbers) % 2 == 0):
    medianOfNumbers = (numbers[int((len(numbers))/2)] + numbers[int((len(numbers))/2-1)])/2
  else:
    medianOfNumbers = numbers[int((len(numbers)-1)/2)]
  return medianOfNumbers

def mode(numbers):
  modeOfNumbers = int(mode(numbers))
  return modeOfNumbers

print("The mean of the months is: " + str("%.2f" % round(mean(months))))
print("The median of the months is: " + str("%.2f" % round(median(months))))
print("The mode of the months is: " + str(mode(months)))
```

And this is the error:

```
The mean of the months is: 7.00
The median of the months is: 8.00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-ad10a2f4e71b> in <module>()
     33 print("The mean of the months is: " + str("%.2f" % round(mean(months))))
     34 print("The median of the months is: " + str("%.2f" % round(median(months))))
---> 35 print("The mode of the months is: " + str(mode(months)))
     36 
     37 

<ipython-input-29-ad10a2f4e71b> in mode(numbers)
     28 
     29 def mode(numbers):
---> 30   modeOfNumbers = int(mode(numbers))
     31   return modeOfNumbers
     32 

... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-29-ad10a2f4e71b> in mode(numbers)
     28 
     29 def mode(numbers):
---> 30   modeOfNumbers = int(mode(numbers))
     31   return modeOfNumbers
     32 

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: You have no exit condition in `mode()`

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Inside your `mode`, you're trying to call `statistics.mode`, but when you write `mode(numbers)` it means the function you have defined called `mode`. So it's an infinite recursion.

Comment: THank you.......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `mode`, you're trying to call `statistics.mode`, but when you write `mode(numbers)` it means the function you have defined called `mode`. So it's an infinite recursion.

If you must have a function called `mode` and also make use of `statistics.mode`, you can use its qualified name to distinguish which one you mean.

```
import statistics

...

def mode(numbers):
    return int(statistics.mode(numbers))
```